# The significance of a comma? R programming

Tags: r

Performing the practice assignment before assignment 1 on Coursera's R course.

The practice assignment shows [, "Day"], but I found ["Day"] obtains the same result. Why are they putting a comma before the column header "Day"?

```
> andy[which(andy[, "Day"] == 30), "Weight"]   
[1] 135   
> andy[which(andy["Day"] == 30), "Weight"]    
[1] 135
```

**Additional information - Structure (str)**

```
> str(andy)  
'data.frame':   30 obs. of  4 variables:  
 $ Patient.Name: Factor w/ 1 level "Andy": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...  
 $ Age         : int  30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 ...  
 $ Weight      : int  140 140 140 139 138 138 138 138 138 138 ...  
 $ Day         : int  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
```

Comment: A data.frame can be treated like a matrix or like a list, and there are methods supporting both.

Comment: Have you tried examining the output of andy[,"Day"] and andy["Day"] directly?

Comment: Have a look at the examples on the ``?`[.data.frame` `` help page.

Comment: You can also do ```andy[which(andy$Day == 30), "Weight"]```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a little "cheat sheet" that might be helpful for understanding the different ways to subset data.frames and the classes of the respective outputs. The comma you asked about results in a vectorized version of the column being selected. Not using a column returns the a data.frame version of that column. You can also use `$` notation like I've done below.

```
andy = data.frame(Day = c(1:30), Weight = round(rnorm(30, 138, 1), 0))
andy[which(andy["Day"] == 30), "Weight"]    
#[1] 138

andy[which(andy[,"Day"] == 30), "Weight"]   
#[1] 138

andy[which(andy$Day == 30), "Weight"]   
#[1] 138

andy$Weight[andy$Day == 30]
#[1] 138

andy$Weight[andy["Day"] == 30]
#[1] 138

andy$Weight[andy[,"Day"] == 30]
#[1] 138

subset(andy, andy$Day == 30)$Weight
#[1] 138

subset(andy, andy$Day == 30)["Weight"]
#   Weight
#30    138

subset(andy, andy$Day == 30)[,"Weight"]
#[1] 138

class(andy["Day"])
#[1] "data.frame"

andy["Day"]
#    Day
# 1    1
# 2    2
# 3    3
...

class(andy[,"Day"])
#[1] "integer"

andy[,"Day"]
#[1]  1  2  3  4  5  6 ...

class(andy$Day)
#[1] "integer"

andy$Day
#[1]  1  2  3  4  5  6 ...
```